# Why is the defrost cycle of an HVAC so loud?

Tags: hvac

During the colder months when defrost mode switches on it can run for roughly ten minutes to thaw out the unit.  I understand that.  My question is why is it so loud?  Why does it have to make such a loud noise to defrost the system?  Is it not possible to make a defrost cycle more silent?

Comment: This is a Heat Pump system?  How would you describe the noise?  Is it constant or just when the defrost mode starts?

Comment: @JPhi1618 It's the loud buzzing the occurs when the system is in defrost.  Yes, it's a heat pump.

Answer (score 2):

The defrost cycle is basically just running the heat pump in cooling mode without the outdoor fan. It's not going to be any louder then when it's running in cooling, it's just that the compressor noise is  disguised by the outdoor fan. The same holds true when the heat pump is in heating mode. The same compressor runs and knows no difference between heating, cooling or defrost mode.

Comment: When my unit is running the normal heating cycle it's pretty quiet.  I could easily have a conversation with someone without trouble.  When defrost kicks in the buzzing sound is so loud that we have to almost yell.

Answer (score 0):

What you're hearing is the reversing valve changing position. The reversing vale as the name implies reverses the flow of refrigerant when the valve changes position. When that happens a loud whoosh sound can be heard  which may be what you're hearing.

I just read your comment about the loud buzzing. That is the compressor. Sound blankets exist to cover the compressor and help with deadening the noise.

Units with an inverter driven compressor  in addition to a sound blanket operate extremely quietly.  You are interested take a look at Mitsubishi's ductless units sound specs